# Is rank of elliptic curve constant under any group law?

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

**Does the rank of an elliptic curve remain same under any group law?**

Say, we have an elliptic curve of rank 2 and we are working over rationals and we are using lines to produce other rational points.

Then if I use the same elliptic curve but instead of using lines I use some other curves to produce other points (using different group law), is the number of independent points again 2?

**EDIT: Answer to dan_fulea's comment:**

If I use parabolas instead of lines:

$$E : y^2=x^3+17^2x$$
$$C_1 : y=\frac{863 x^2}{18496}+\frac{803 x}{136}-\frac{157}{4}$$
$$C_2 : y=\frac{231 x^2}{5776}+\frac{9835 x}{1444}-\frac{25296}{361}$$
$$C_3 : y=\frac{12 x^2}{247}+\frac{2465 x}{494}+\frac{3468}{247}$$
Known points $[P_1, P_2, P_3]$:
$$P_1=(68,578),P_2=(144,1740),P_3=(\frac{17}{4},\frac{289}{8})$$
New points constructed by intersections of $E$ with $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$, $[N_1, N_2, N_3]$:
$$N_1=(\frac{1676132}{744769},-\frac{16534737914}{642735647}),N_2=(\frac{246016}{53361},-\frac{466192880}{12326391}),N_3=(\frac{289}{144},\frac{41905}{1728})$$
$$C_1 \cap E=[P_1, P_1, P_1, N_1]$$
$$C_2 \cap E=[P_1, P_1, P_2, N_2]$$
$$C_3 \cap E=[P_1, P_2, P_3, N_3]$$

I could have used other curves not just parabolas with even more contacts.

**But I now see that all this can be done using lines.**
For example $N_1=-3*P_1$. So perhaps I need as many independent points with parabolas as I would need with lines.

Comment: To have a **rank** we should have a group. Which group of rational points do you construct using "other curves"?

Comment: @dan_fulea I do not choose which group. The elliptic curve is given and I want to construct all its rational points as linear combination of independent points.

Comment: Why should there be any different group law? Did you check associativity for you "new group law"? All is over $\Bbb Q$, as you said.

Comment: @azerbajdzan But there is an explicit question in bold faced line containing the word **rank**, and well, *any group law* assumes tacitly that we have some group, possibly some other group to also have a question. Please introduce exactly the objects one by one, best with an example and the own tries. In the second we have a well defined question, we may also have an immediate answer. Let us consider for instance $$E\ :\ y^2 = x^3+17^2x\ .$$It contains the points $(68, 578)$, $(144, 1740)$ and it will contain them w.r.t. any group law. How should we add and/or double them?

Comment: "Any group law" is rather vague. I mean, you can take a group of rank $1$, biject it with an arbitrary countable group, and use transport of structure to give it whatever countable group structure you want to give it (you could make it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$). But of course, that structure wouldn't have anything to do with the fact that these are rational points on an elliptic curve, so what would be the point?

Comment: @dan_fulea: I answered by editing my question above.